# GrailsFlow plugin installation -with Grails 2.0.4

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have downloaded GrailsFlow [GrailsFlow 1.1-RC1 plugin and demo application](http://www.grailsflow.org/download/grailsflow-src-1.1-RC1.zip) and was trying to run the appliaction in my local. I have grails version 2.0.4 .

i am not able to run the application and which gives me following error

```
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/grails-jxl-2.6.2.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5: not found

            :: net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2: not found

            :: net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


  :: problems summary ::
  :::: WARNINGS
            module not found: com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo/lib/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/com.lowagie/iTextAsian/ivy-2.1.5.xml

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/com.lowagie/iTextAsian/jars/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/com.lowagie/iTextAsian/bundles/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/iTextAsian-2.1.5.xml

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/iTextAsian-2.1.5.xml

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/iTextAsian-2.1.5.xml

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../plugins/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-iTextAsian/tags/RELEASE_2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.pom

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-iTextAsian/tags/RELEASE_2.1.5/grails-iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/com/lowagie/iTextAsian/2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.pom

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/com/lowagie/iTextAsian/2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/lowagie/iTextAsian/2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.pom

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/lowagie/iTextAsian/2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-iTextAsian/tags/RELEASE_2.1.5/iTextAsian-2.1.5.pom

      -- artifact com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5!iTextAsian.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-iTextAsian/tags/RELEASE_2.1.5/grails-iTextAsian-2.1.5.jar

            module not found: net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo/lib/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/ivy-2.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/jars/opencsv-2.2.jar

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/bundles/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/opencsv-2.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/opencsv-2.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/opencsv-2.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../plugins/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-opencsv/tags/RELEASE_2.2/opencsv-2.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-opencsv/tags/RELEASE_2.2/grails-opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.2/opencsv-2.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.2/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.2/opencsv-2.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.2/opencsv-2.2.jar

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-opencsv/tags/RELEASE_2.2/opencsv-2.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2!opencsv.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-opencsv/tags/RELEASE_2.2/grails-opencsv-2.2.jar

            module not found: net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo/lib/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/ivy-2.6.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/jars/jxl-2.6.2.jar

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../lib/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/bundles/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/jxl-2.6.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\src\libs/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/jxl-2.6.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\dist/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/jxl-2.6.2.xml

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\Workspace\grailsflow-demo\target\cached-installed-plugins/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\../plugins/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://plugins.grails.org/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/grails-jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.jar

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/jxl-2.6.2.pom

      -- artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2!jxl.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jxl/tags/RELEASE_2.6.2/grails-jxl-2.6.2.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: com.lowagie#iTextAsian;2.1.5: not found

            :: net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.2: not found

            :: net.sourceforge.jexcelapi#jxl;2.6.2: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


    | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- com.lowagie:iTextAsian:2.1.5
- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.2
- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.2
```

anybody has got any idea about resolving this ?

my buildConfig.groovy file

```
         grails.work.dir = "target"
```

grails.project.war.file = "${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.plugin.location.'grailsflow-core' = '../grailsflow-core'

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits "global"
    log "warn"

```
repositories {
    grailsHome()
    mavenCentral()
    if (buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenLocal) {
        mavenLocal buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenLocal
    }
    if (buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenCentral) {
        mavenRepo buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenCentral
    }
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsCentral()
}

dependencies {
    runtime ('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6')
    compile ('com.sdicons.jsontools:jsontools-core:1.7')
    compile ('commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1')
}

plugins {
    // external plugins
    runtime("com.jcatalog.grailsplugins:hibernate:${grailsVersion}")
    runtime("org.grails.plugins:tomcat:${grailsVersion}")
    runtime("org.grails.plugins:resources:1.1.6")
    runtime('org.grails.plugins:quartz:0.4.2',
            'org.grails.plugins:mail:0.7.1',
            'org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.7.1',
            'org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.8.15',
            'org.grails.plugins:jqplot:0.1')
    runtime('org.grails.plugins:export:0.9') {
      excludes "odfdom", 'xercesImpl'   // Fixing exception during build
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` to the repositories block in your `BuildConfig` (or uncommenting it if it's there but commented out). I thought it was included by default in new projects with Grails 2 but the error you've given suggests it's missing in this case.

Comment: i already have something 
    grailsHome()
  mavenCentral()
        if (buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenLocal) {
            mavenLocal buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenLocal
        }
        if (buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenCentral) {
            mavenRepo buildSettings.config.jcatalog.mavenCentral
        }
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsCentral()
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try to use plugin ":export:1.0" instead of ":export:0.9".
It works in my case.